# Foundation 6 slider: range stating from negative values

Tags: slider, range, zurb-foundation, negative-number

I wander if in foundation 6 sliders, it is possible to allow negative values e.g. swinging from -50 to 50.

Currently I have a slider in [0 100]:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-4 large-4 columns">
    <label>Audio&nbsp;Volume</label>
  </div>
  <div class="small-6 large-6 columns">
    <div class="slider" id="slidervol" data-slider data-end="100" display_selector: "#slidervol">
      <span class="slider-handle" data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1" aria-controls="sliderVolOutput"></span>
      <span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-2 large-2 columns">
    <input name="AudioVolTxtbox" type="number" style="width: 4em;" tabindex="2" id="sliderVolOutput">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a negative `start` value, but the behaviour is unpredictable when you do so. If you want to make use of negative values, you'll need logic to update the value in `#sliderVolOutput` after the handle has been moved.

The `moved.zf.slider` event is triggered every time the handle is moved and you can use that fact to update the textbox value. This event is fired quite a few times, so you'll need to add additional code to get rid of the flickering (if it's bothersome).

I've provided some basic code that should get you started. If you have any questions, please let me know.

```
var target = document.getElementById("slidervol");
var options = {
  "start": 0,
  "end": 100,
  "decimal": 0
};

var elem = new Foundation.Slider($(target), options);
var offset = 50;

$(target).on('moved.zf.slider', function() {
    $('#sliderVolOutput').val(Number($('.slider-handle').attr('aria-valuenow')) - offset);
});
```

Another approach would be to use the `mousemove.zf.slider` event. This gets rid of the flicker, but the textbox value is only updated once you've stopped manipulating the slider:

```
$(target).on('mousemove.zf.slider', function() {
    $('#sliderVolOutput').val(Number($('.slider-handle').attr('aria-valuenow')) - offset);
});
```

---

**UPDATE:**

In response to your additional query, I've had time to implement the required functionality (editing the value in the text box causing the slider to update) using a hidden control.

The `slider-handle` now targets the hidden control (`aria-controls`), which will always contain a positive value. The text box will contain the negative (computed) value. This is what the updated html looks like for the `slider-handle`:

```
<span class="slider-handle" data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1" aria-controls="sliderVolOutputHidden"></span>
```

And this is the additional hidden input I've used:

```
<input type="hidden" id="sliderVolOutputHidden" value="0">
```

I've also added an `input` event for `#sliderVolOutput` that updates the value of the hidden `input` and triggers the `change` event. The `change` event is important, as without it, the handle will not update:

```
$('#sliderVolOutput').on('input', function() {
  $('#sliderVolOutputHidden').val(Number($('#sliderVolOutput').val()) + offset);
  $('#sliderVolOutputHidden').trigger('change');
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/3L1xavz2/)

Comment: I used you examples to try to patch the foundation.js but there is still some work to do.

Comment: In order for the textbox input to work, it'll need more work. I've not had time to look into the issue yet, but as soon as I do, I'll get back to you.

Comment: @peregrinus I finally had time to look into your issue. Please see my updated post. The fiddle has also been updated. If you have any more questions, I'll be happy to answer them.

Comment: Fantastic, your solution works greatly.  Thank you Yass!

Comment: You're welcome. To the downvoter, can you please explain your reason?

Comment: @peregrinus I think you may have accidentally downvoted my answer.

Comment: Yes, sorry for accidentally downvoting. There is still some issue I am trying to understand when I add two sliders:
    [Fiddle Demo] https://jsfiddle.net/p3r3gr1nus/kzk11m8c/4/

Comment: You need to initialize the second slider and target them using `class`es instead of `id`s. In your fiddle, you've got duplicate classes, which you can't have. Here's an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kzk11m8c/5/)

Comment: No probs. Please consider accepting my answer as it has helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I get quite a result patching as follows foundation.js.
I can change values smoothly with the slider (with no flickering) but I can not decrement the textbox (aria-controls) below 0 since he event handler does not fire.

```
@@ -6953,13 +6953,14 @@
           'id': id,
           'max': this.options.end,
           'min': this.options.start,
+          'offset': this.options.offset,
           'step': this.options.step
         });
         this.handles.eq(idx).attr({
           'role': 'slider',
           'aria-controls': id,
-          'aria-valuemax': this.options.end,
-          'aria-valuemin': this.options.start,
+          'aria-valuemax': this.options.end + this.options.offset,
+          'aria-valuemin': this.options.start + this.options.offset,
           'aria-valuenow': idx === 0 ? this.options.initialStart : this.options.initialEnd,
           'aria-orientation': this.options.vertical ? 'vertical' : 'horizontal',
           'tabindex': 0
@@ -6978,8 +6979,8 @@
       key: '_setValues',
       value: function _setValues($handle, val) {
         var idx = this.options.doubleSided ? this.handles.index($handle) : 0;
-        this.inputs.eq(idx).val(val);
-        $handle.attr('aria-valuenow', val);
+        this.inputs.eq(idx).val(val+this.options.offset);
+        $handle.attr('aria-valuenow', val+this.options.offset);
       }

       /**
@@ -7033,7 +7034,8 @@
         } else {
           //change event on input
           value = this._adjustValue(null, val);
-          hasVal = true;
+            value = value - this.options.offset;
+          hasVal = true;          
         }

         this._setHandlePos($handle, value, hasVal);
@@ -7286,7 +7288,13 @@
      * @option
      * @example false
      */
-    invertVertical: false
+    invertVertical: false,
+    /**
+     * 
+     * @option
+     * @example 0
+     */
+     offset: 0
   };

   function percent(frac, num) {
```

Then, for instance I want to change my parameter "Audio Volume" from -24 to 24 so in js:

```
// Audio Volume                         
        vartxt = GetParameter("AudioVolume") // get the value in some way
        tval = parseFloat(vartxt);
        document.DeviceConfig.AudioVolTxtbox.value = tval - 24; //change the textbox

        var target = document.getElementById("slidervol");    
        var options = {
            "start": 0,
            "end": 48,
            "decimal": 0,
            "step": 1,
            "offset": -24,  
            "initialStart": tval
        };
        var elem = new Foundation.Slider($(target), options);
```

At the moment the only problem I get is that I have to configure the input box as 'text', since if I set it as 'number' the spinner does not allow to go below the 0.